# E2E tests that rely on a test Facebook app hitting test user creation limits

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm writing an e2e suite which tests internal business logic relating to merging accounts from different origins.

We have multiple cases that require unique Facebook users.

Currently I am `publishing` and `deleting` a user at the beginning and end of each test.

I am using the edge Facebook graph API and after running the suite locally a few times, it starts hitting the user creation limits (not total users, but rate limit for creating users).

What's the best way to test Facebook login?

Comment: Is it necessary to delete the users in the end? Couldn't you create a set of test users and reuse them?

Comment: It's required that unique emails be used, though come to think of it, I could just delete the user out of the user storage and reuse the generated facebook user

Comment: Yep, I think that's your best bet.